# I’m looking for a big book of magic related stories

Tags: story-identification, magic

I had it as a kid and lost it in 1978. I don’t remember the title but I think it was like the biggest book of magic...

One story was about a guy who invented or found a tube and when he held it up, looked through and blinked, it left a hole in whatever was in view.

Another story (though it might be from a different book) was about a guy who finds clay pebbles in a cave and passed the time tossing them off a cliff. He sticks a couple in his bag and when he gets home from his vacation he discovers that the clay was covering perfect precious gems.

Comment: The second story is The Balls of Clay, found in the book Strangely Enough! by C.B. Colby.

Comment: @Frock Post that as an answer, even if you can't identify the collection.

Answer (score 5):

The first story is *[Seven-Day Terror](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40956)* by R. A. Lafferty. First appeared in [Worlds of If](https://archive.org/stream/1962-03_IF_modified#page/n93/mode/2up), March 1962

The second story is *[The Balls of Clay](https://tommcnulty.blogspot.com/2016/09/strangely-enough-by-c-b-colby.html)*, from Strangely Enough! by C. B.[Carroll Burleigh] Colby.

I can't find an anthology where they were published together, though.